# What's the appropriate syntax for this dictionary comprehension fully written out?

Tags: python

I'm trying to debug some code that includes a dictionary comprehension. Just want to make sure I have this correct and that I add a print line to view the `key`s as well. Here's the comprehension one-liner:

```
gooditems = {key: value for key, value in row.items() if key in fields}
```

Thinking of adding the following to view keys:

```
for key, value in row.items():
    print(key,value)
```

Is it as easy as that?

Comment: Do you mean dictionary or list? For a list you will have to use `for index, val in enumerate(list)`

Comment: Oops yeah I meant dictionary comprehension

Comment: I'm not sure what is the question here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is equivalent to this if this is what you are asking:

```
gooditems = {}
for key, value in row.items():
    if key in fields:
        gooditems[key] = value
```